# Error Packaging into a Phar file an entire Slim Application

Tags: php, slim, phar

I have a Slim Application with the following directory structure:

```
app/
vendor/
www/

config.php
```

In app/ I have the relevant files of the project, in vendor/ the dependencies managed by composer and in www/ the files accesible by the web server.

So I am thinking to create a Phar file along the lines of:

```
<?php

$full_path = '/home/.../forms/';
$package_name = 'www/package.phar';

try {
    $phar = new Phar($full_path . $package_name, 
    FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO |       FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_FILENAME, $full_path . $package_name);

$phar->startBuffering();

$phar->addFile($full_path . 'www/index.php');
$phar->addFile($full_path . 'www/bootstrap.php');
$phar->addFile($full_path . 'www/session_start.php');


// Grab config
$phar->addFile($full_path . 'config.php');


$phar->buildFromIterator(new RecursiveIteratorIterator (new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('../app', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)),'../app');
$phar->buildFromIterator(new RecursiveIteratorIterator (new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('../vendor', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)),'../vendor');

$phar->setDefaultStub('bootstrap.php', 'bootstrap.php');

$phar->stopBuffering();

echo "Phar created.";

} catch (Exception $e) {
// handle errors here
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

So I create that way the phar and then I have:

deploy.php

```
<?php

require_once 'phar://package.phar/bootstrap.php';
$app->run();
```

But when accesing /deploy.php I am getting:

> [Fri May 15 20:07:02 2015] [error] [client 10.0.2.2] PHP Warning: 
>   require_once(phar://package.phar/bootstrap.php) [function.require-once]: failed to
>   open stream: Cannot open archive
>   "/vagrant/www/package.phar", invalid alias in
>   /vagrant/www/deploy.php on line 3 [Fri May 15 20:07:02 2015] [error]
>   [client 10.0.2.2] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   'phar://package.phar/bootstrap.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /vagrant/www/deploy.php on line 3

Do you think I should be addressing it like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

"Creating the phar in a shared folder of a Vagrant box caused that problem. Once I changed "output" property to a location outside the shared folder the error went away." 
[source](http://github.com/box-project/box2/issues/90)

---

You should check your php.ini:
`phar.require_hash = Off`

Or sign your Phar with [setSignatureAlgorithm()](http://php.net/manual/fr/phardata.setsignaturealgorithm.php)

Or with Phing:
`<pharpackage ...  signature="sha512"> ...`

Comment: Hi, Set `phar.require_hash = Off` but still giving me the same error

Comment: Well, can you explicit the local names in [http://php.net/manual/en/phar.addfile.php](addFile())

Comment: Do you mean by that, something like this?: 
`$phar->addFile($full_path . 'www/index.php', 'www/index.php');` ..., done that, rebuilt the phar, and still unable to include it, getting the `invalid alias` error when doing: `include 'phar://package.phar/www/bootstrap.php';`

Comment: I am doing it with Phing now so it seems that the error is that the Phar generated the old way was corrupted, Phing throws me: 

`BUILD FAILED
/vagrant/build.xml:16:9: Problem creating package: unable to copy stub of old phar to new phar "/vagrant/www/package.phar" [wrapped: unable to copy stub of old phar to new phar "/vagrant/www/package.phar"]`

Any hint? Thanks!

Comment: I found that: "Creating the phar in a shared folder of a Vagrant box caused that problem. Once I changed "output" property to a location outside the shared folder the error went away."
source: https://github.com/box-project/box2/issues/90

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue to this, you get the bounty :).

As a side note, after fixing this issue, I came across to another error: `unable to create temporary file`: This is a known PHP bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53467

Comment: Could you update your answer please so if someone comes across this in the future they see it quickly? :)